# WebView en AlertDialog

Tags: android, webview, alertdialog, google-drive

Buenos días a todos:
Estoy tratando de colocar un WebView en un AlertDialog el cual quiero que muestre un Documento compartido de Google Drive, del cual conozco su URL pública.

Cuando yo indico una URL (ejm. google.com), el WebView se muestra correctamente, pero cuando indico la URL del archivo compartido, la altura del WebView es muy pequeña.

He probado muchos códigos pero todos tienen el mismo problema, aquí les dejo el código.

```
private void CargarURL (String sURL) {

        final View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alertnotic, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        final WebView webview  = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wNotic);
        String url = sURL;
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl(url);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setView(view);
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                //dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.colorAccentDark));

            }
        });
        // display dialog
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Unas capturas: con url de archivo (la parte de color negro es el WebView, aparentemente si carga el archivo online pero no se muestra correctamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con url de google
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor, tengamos cuidado al generar etiquetas nuevas, que no existan otras etiquetas para lo mismo

Comment: Has intentado otra url como facebook?